# How do I get javascript to run on Reveal.js slides? (specifically HighCharts)

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts, reveal.js

I'd like to get highcharts graphs to appear on slides in Reveal.js -- is this possible? I've tried copying my container and js into the slide elements, to no avail.

Comment: Make sure you have set width and height for container. See also [this](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/frequently-asked-questions#jquery-ui-tab).

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23539399/1057708). You can do it with slide state events.