# execute function when certain slide appear in reveal.js

Tags: javascript, html, reveal.js

I create a presentation with this javascript framework http://lab.hakim.se/reveal-js/#/ and when certain slide is appearing I want to execute function stats(), which display some data from API every 5 seconds, but only when this slide is appearing

```
function stats(){                
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url_survey,
    dataType: "json",
    success : 
      function (data) {
      //some code to display data       
    },
    error:
      //some code
}); 
}
```

in HTML file I have this:

```
<section>
<div id="stats">
</div>
</section>
```

how can I do it? I wrote this code, but it works always, not only when slide appear

```
function check(){
if($("#stats").is(":visible"))
stats();
}

check();
setInterval(function(){check()}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 23):

This can be achieved by using reveal.js states (https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js#states).

**1) Add a unique state to the section that should trigger your method.**

```
<section data-state="stats">
    <h2>This will trigger a state event with the name "stats".</h2>
</section>
```

**2) Add a listener to your custom state using the reveal.js API.**

```
Reveal.addEventListener( 'stats', function() {
    // Called each time the slide with the "stats" state is made visible
} );
```

Complete working example: https://gist.github.com/hakimel/cea4305a33713d4a5a7e

Comment: yes, but I need have in HTML this: <section><div id="stats"></div></section> ... is there some other solution how to make it in external js file @hakim

Comment: Cool, is it possible to pass arguments to the event handler function? Thanks

Comment: @Felipe I'm not sure if it's the best solution, but using datasets you can add in your slide something like `data-your-data="42"` and then inside your callback function you can access it using `Reveal.getCurrentSlide().dataset.pluginPage`.

Answer (score 1):

To answer Philippe Leefsma's question: you can use bind() to pass arguments, like so:

```
drawDiagramOnSlide.bind(
    null,
    slideName,
    slideEl.querySelector('.diagram')
));
```

Assuming drawDiagramOnSlide looks like this:

```
function drawDiagramOnSlide(_slideName, _diagramEl, _event) {...}
```

The bind call will create a function that calls drawDiagramOnSlide with the correct slide name and element (in my case, a div with class diagram inside the slide ).